# How to write a void function that will search for values in an array and pass the position of that value back to main function by reference?

Tags: c++, arrays, function, for-loop, search

User will enter a value (size) which represents the number of values to process. The values entered will be stored in an array of type short that has 1000 elements. User will enter size numbers. The user will enter a search value. The program will search the data for a specific value. Program will display a message in which element the value was found or display a message the value was not found

// Function to search the array using a sequential search

// Assign the subscript/element # to offset where found or assign offset -1 if not found.

void sequential_search(short data[], short size, short search_value, short &offset)

```
for (int n = 0; n < size; n++)
{
    if (search_value == data[n])
        offset = n;
    else 
        offset = -1;
}
```

I'm only finding a value for the last element of the array, and I'm confused about where to go from here. If I take the else statement out, I get the positions of the values in the array, but it also gives any number value the last position in the array.

Answer (score 0):

Do offset = -1 before the *for* statement. Any negative finds you do after a good find will corrupt your good find.

This is very not idiomatic c++.
The idiomatic way would be to use find.

```
auto data_result = std::find(data, data + size, element);
auto offset = data_result - data;
```